# Programmatically created nodes are not appearing under table 'nodes'

Tags: 7, nodes

I have written a PHP script for the programmatic creation of nodes:

```
<?php

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = "localhost";
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

// Get a list of Office ID's
$office_ids = db_query('SELECT OFFICE_ID FROM sage.OFFICE');

// Loop through and edit each user
foreach($office_ids as $office) {

  // Create a new node object
  $node = new stdClass();

  // Set our new node content type
  $node->type = "office";

  // Set the node title
  $node->title = "Office " . $office->office_id;

  // Set the language
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

  // Set the UID of the author of the node; or use $node->name
  $node->uid = 1;

  // Set node details
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = $bodytext;
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = text_summary($bodytext);
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'filtered_html';

  $path = 'office-' . $office->office_id;
  $node->path = array('alias' => $path);

  if($node = node_submit($node)) {
    node_save($node);
    echo "Node with nid" . $node->nid . " saved!\n";
  }
}
```

When I run the above script, I can see my NIDs incrementing (and I assume this means my nodes are created), however when I go and check in the 'nodes' table in the database, I see nothing added.

Does anything know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$node` object you pass to `node_save()` wouldn't get it's `nid` member populated unless the node has been successfully saved to the `node` table in the database.

The auto-increment ID actually comes from the database table so if the `$node` object has a `nid`, you can pretty much guarantee the record has been successfully inserted into the table.

Make sure that the software you're using to view the table doesn't have some sort of paging turned on, meaning that only the first x number of records are actually showing in your results. Most MySQL UI software (PHPMyAdmin, Navicat, etc.) limit the number of results you see in a table by default; if you want to see more you need to change the setting.

If you want to do a quick check run the following query on your database:

```
SELECT MAX(nid) FROM node
```

Note down that number, then run your code again. Finally run the above query one more time. If the `nid` you get the second time around is greater than the one from the first time round, you know the record has definitely been added to the database.

Comment: Clive, I just did that but my nid has not changed, therefore not causing any nodes to be added to my 'node' table. Would you have any ideas as to why my code is not adding?

Comment: I can't think of a single good reason why it's not working, if you step through the [`node_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7) function you'll see that it throws an error if it fails to save to the node table. Since you don't get that error it would suggest the record is definitely being saved. Silly question I'm sure: are you absolutely certain you're connecting Drupal to the same database as you're viewing once you've run your code?

Comment: thank you...it has been added to the default drupal database for my default site, as I run a multi-site installation. I am running this script in /var/www/drupal7, then is there a way for me to add this to another database?

Comment: No problem :) Have you seen the [`db_set_active()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_set_active/7) function? That's normally the way to switch databases in code

Comment: Clive, my database name is 'sage' and I tried db_set_active('sage'); before I do any DB related work, but this doesn't seem to be working. Would you have some ideas?

Comment: You'll need to add another database connection in settings.php, or build up the connection as an array on the fly, to make that work. There's some pretty comprehensive instructions [here](http://drupal.org/node/18429) that should help you out

Comment: All in favour of @Clive being renames as Captain Helpful? ;-)

Comment: @Chapabu Heh, more like Captain There's-nothing-good-on-the-telly ;)

Comment: 1 vote from me!